# Multiple Windows in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm testing Android Studio, it looks great but have very differences with Eclipse.

I work with multiple monitors, how can I open the same project several times?

I don't like to drag a tab and have a floating windows without tool bars or menus, I wan't a similar window like the Eclipse's `Window/New Window` option.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well yeah i agree , since Eclipse is IDE and android creates just plugin, so the OPEN IN NEW WINDOW is eclipse's feature .. 
And the Android Studio Developers didnt think that it was appropriate to provide that feature . You can open the .java file with notepad++ on one of the monitor and the xml file in Android Studio on another monitor

Note:(based on past experience)
You will have to clean up(Refresh/Re-factor)  the build for staying away from errors as the File isnt locked (like in linux system) when you open it with notepad++ .. so it can create a havoc .. (happened to me sometimes )